# How to use ionic grid with full screen cordova google maps?

Tags: google-maps, cordova, ionic-framework, flexbox

I'm trying to display labels and buttons on top of cordova google maps in an Ionic 3 app. I would like to have a full screen map with labels (and then buttons) on top of the map. I searched extensively without much success on stackoverflow, Ionic forum and on Google to find whether it is possible to overlap a fullscreen map with ion-grid layer of labels (and buttons). Here's my home.html

```
<ion-content class="home">
  <ion-grid>
    <div #map id="map" style="height:100%;">
      <ion-row style="flex:1;">
        <button ion-button icon-only (click)="openMenu()">
          <ion-icon name="menu">
          </ion-icon>
        </button>
      </ion-row>
      <ion-row style="flex:1;">
        <ion-col col-1>
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col col-8>
          <ion-item>
            <ion-label (click)="onStartLocation()">Start Location</ion-label>
          </ion-item>
        </ion-col>
      </ion-row>
      <ion-row style="flex:4;">
      </ion-row>
      <ion-row style="flex:1;">
        <ion-col col-5>
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col>
          <ion-item>
            <ion-label (click)="onEndLocation()">End Location</ion-label>
          </ion-item>
        </ion-col>
      </ion-row>
      <ion-row style="flex:1;">
      </ion-row>
    </div>
  </ion-grid>
</ion-content>
```

I'm wondering what mistake I'm making in the above code because when I run the code, the labels are out of alignment and are positioned one below the other instead of spaced apart. The flex directives seem to have no effect. I've created a git repo. It can be found here: https://github.com/id4coding/gmapsionic.git

Any help in fixing the template/layout is much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you should add !important after each style attribute value ;
for example:
style="height:100% !important;"

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried the !important suffix. But it didn't fix the layout issue. The buttons are still not getting spaced apart.